# Div text won't show up as it should

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem with my div, when I'm trying to put text inside a div using `<?php echo $uin->text; ?>` it doesn't show up like I want it to.

So if it worked it should have looked like this:

```
    SOME TEXT HERE
    
    
    
    
    SOME TEXT SOME LINES BELOW


MORE TEXT AT THE BOTOM
```

but for me it always shows up like this

```
SOME TEXT HERE SOME TEXT SOME LINES BELOW MORE TEXT AT THE BOTOM
```

Here is the codes I've tried:

```
<style>
.TextAndStuff {
background: url(<?php echo $uin->backgroundimg; ?>);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}
  </style>
  <div class="TextAndStuff">
  <?php echo $uin->text; ?>
  </div>
```

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong but if there's like 3 lines between the top text and the middle text in `$uin->text` it doesn't show those line, everything just gets on the same line.

Comment: `nl2br()` function

Comment: html will ignore multiple white space (spaces, tabs and returns). It also doesn't understand what a normal return character is. @u_mulder is telling you to use a built in function that will change the returns in your string `$uin->text` into `<br>`. This way, they will be displayed on new lines.  `nl2br($uin->text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @u_mulder and @ThrowBackDewd said on the top, use `nl2br()` function.

In your case, it would be like this :

```
  <div class="TextAndStuff">
  <?php echo nl2br($uin->text); ?>
  </div>
```